# Variables in event handler function is not dynamically resolving. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, addeventlistener, offset

I'm having a list html element. I want to check the offsetheight of a child element which hides/toggles alternatively when clicked. The offsetheight is zero when its hidden and 76 when revealed.

So, I have created a click event listener to the parent element wherein I assign the offsetheight of its child element to a JavaScript variable. Problem is the JavaScript variable always returns zero ie, the initial offsetheight value at the time of declaring the event listener.

The value isn't changing dynamically. Though, in the browser console, I could see the offset height value changing between zero and 76. What's the reason for all this or what I should do to dynamically capture the offset properties of a toggling element? And p.s, there is no toggle event happening here. Toggle event listener is not helping me.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery('.container-tabs.hidden-xs.hidden-sm').click(function(){
    var a = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(a);
    var height=document.querySelector('div'+a).offsetheight;
    console.log(height);
});
```

The parent class's href attributes is the classname of the child element. I have used it to select the child element( I have used other direct selectors too but didn't help).The variable height always returns zero regardless of the element being visible or hidden.

Comment: Could you provide more details like the value of `href` and `document.querySelector('div'+a)` ? And its `offsetHeight` not `offsetheight`.

Comment: The value of href is #menu4 exactly the id of toggling element. I tried offsetHeight too still returns 0 even when the element reveals. document.querySelector('div'+a) returns div#menu4.

Comment: I just have trouble with how dynamic variables are getting resolved inside event handler function.

Comment: Can you post your code as JS Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ ? It will be easy to debug. Variables inside event handlers resolves the same way when it is declared outside. But their scope is within the event handler function